# railway=* doesn't extract rails

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I'm trying to extract everything related to railways from pbf file using osmosis. I've tried several ways but couldn't find a solution. I got everthing about railways extracted except rails. Here is what I've tried latest:

```
osmosis --read-pbf file=turkey-latest.osm.pbf --tf accept-nodes railway=* --tf reject-relations --tf reject-ways --write-xml yollar.osm
```

If I remove --tf reject-ways I will have enourmously large data.

I'm using Osmosis v0.47 and latest pbf data.

Comment: Have you tried `railway=rail`?

Comment: Yes. It returns zero results, 1 kb empty osm file.

Comment: Is there a specific reason, you only want to get railway-nodes, but nothing else? Especially, when rails are linear features...

Comment: Yes, I only need those for my project.

Comment: Have you considered getting the nodes form overpass-turbo instead?

Comment: I just checked with the Geofabrik-data for Germany: There are only line-features for railways, no nodes/points. So, your request most likely doesn't return anything, because there is nothing to return.

Comment: Yes I've considered it with overpass-turbo but I want to make it automated for updates. After you said line-features I've checked how I handled this and I figured out I'm trying to retrieve nodes but rails are line and I handled in other ways. I will share my solution here, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and with help of @Erik I've found out I'm trying to extract nodes but rails are stated by line. So I found the solution by seperating my osmosis queries.

For extracting anything related railways:

```
osmosis --read-pbf file=turkey-latest.osm.pbf --tf accept-nodes railway=* --tf reject-relations --tf reject-ways --write-xml nodes.osm
```

For extracting rails:

```
osmosis --read-pbf file=turkey-latest.osm.pbf --tf accept-ways railway=rail --tf reject-relations --used-node --write-xml rails.osm
```